# Dar submit em formulário com validações de campos vazios

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esse código que faz validação a um formulário se tem campos vázios senão tiver ele faz o submit do formulário:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var erros = 0;

    $("#formAdd input").each(function () {

        $(this).val() == "" ? erros++ : "";

    });
    $("#formAdd textarea").each(function () {

        $(this).val() == "" ? erros++ : "";

    });

    if (erros > 0) {

        $("#msg").show().fadeIn(500).delay(1500).fadeOut(600);

    } else {
        $(this).submit(function () {
            var form = $(this);
            var dados = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled", true);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'u/add',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: dados,
                type: 'post'
            }).done(function (data) {
                fetchUser();
                alert("Dados Salvos com Sucesso");
                console.log("STATUS : ", data);
                $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled", false);
                $('#modalAddfoto').modal('hide');
                $('.addfoto')[0].reset();
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled", false);
            });
            return false;

        });
    }

});
```

ele válida normal porém não está entrando nessa parte do código:
`$(this).submit(function () { ... }`

Detalhe, se eu tirar a validação e fazer `$('#formAdd').submit(function () { ... }` funciona normalmente.

Comment: `this` nesse contexto está referenciando o #btnAdd e não o form

Comment: o this não está referenciando o form

Comment: Se eu colocar `#formAdd` que é o formulário também não funciona.

Comment: ele chega a entrar no else?

Comment: Entra normal no else.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode vincular o evento de submit diretamente no form, podendo passar o this dele como parâmetro (já fazendo uma referencia ao Angular).

```
<form onsubmit="qualquerEvento(this)">
    <button type="submit">Enviar dados</ button>
</ form>

<script>
    qualquerEvento(e) { // 'e' agora será o form

        // evitando o comportamento padrão
        e.preventDefault();

        // faz as validações dos campos

        // faz o ajax para o servidor
    }
</ script>
```

Vale lembrar que o HTML 5 ele não permite que certos tipos de input sejam enviados com valores nulos, podendo facilitar ainda mais a escrita do código na hora da validação.

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso, o `this` se refere ao botão clicado.
Um botão não tem a ação `submit`, ele pode chamar o submit do form, mas não tem como invocar `$(this).submit()` no botão.

Use `$(this.closest('form')).submit()` para recuperar seu form e então invocar o submit.

Comment: Assim também não funcionou: `$(this.closest('form')).submit()`
Se eu colocar também `#formAdd` não funciona.
Parace que dentro do elese dessa forma não funciona.

Eu testei para ver se está chegando no else colocando um `alert('cheguei')` ele exibe o alerta com as validações ok.

Comment: Certo, se você passar uma função dentro do `submit`, você está definindo um evento para ser chamado no onSubmit, não invocando o onSubmit em si. Se é isso o que você quer, não há porque usar `$().submit`, simplesmente invoque o `$.ajax` diretamente no else.

Comment: Certo, eu preciso enviar o formulário via ajax se os campos estiverem preenchidos.
Eu tentei invocando diretamente o ajax, porém não salva no banco ou seja parace que ele não dar submit no form.

Answer (score 0):

Se o #btnAdd for um `type="submit"` do form, você pode fazer algo como:

```
$(function(){


    $('#formAdd').submit(function(e){

        var erros = 0;

        $("#formAdd input").each(function () {
            $(this).val() == "" ? erros++ : "";
        });
        $("#formAdd textarea").each(function () {
            $(this).val() == "" ? erros++ : "";
        });

        if (erros > 0) {
            $("#msg").show().fadeIn(500).delay(1500).fadeOut(600);
        } else {
            var form = $(this);
            var dados = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled", true);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'u/add',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,

                data: dados, 
                //OU: data: form.serialize(),

                type: 'post'
            }).done(function (data) {
                fetchUser();
                alert("Dados Salvos com Sucesso");
                console.log("STATUS : ", data);
                $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled", false);
                $('#modalAddfoto').modal('hide');
                $('.addfoto')[0].reset();
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                $("#btnAdd").prop("disabled", false);
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });


});
```

Comment: Ele no caso é do tipo button.
No caso do tipo button como ficaria?

Comment: Tipo button ficaria:





`//Chamando click:
$('#yourButtonId').click(function(){

    //Chamando submit do form:
    $('#formAdd').submit();

});`